# How to add inbound rule to AWS security group with my default VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I want to add inbound rule to security group with my default VPC. I removed default VPC from a zone and added a default VPC. But I get fault below :

```
"[AmazonServiceException: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: AmazonEC2, AWS Request ID: c99a21bb-c798-4938-994f-ef8b89c64a72, AWS Error Code: VPCIdNotSpecified, AWS Error Message: No default VPC for this user]"
```

I can add ingress rule on AWS but I can't this on my project which is developed with AWS API.

How can I do?

Comment: You can delete a Default VPC but you cannot create it. Only AWS technical Support can create Default VPC for you. So I am not what exactly you mean when you say **and added a default VPC**

Comment: sorry, I create my VPC but it is not default. You are right. In spite of I can add ingress rule on AWS, I can't this on my project which is developed with AWS API at the same region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved. While I am adding rule, I post security groupId instead of groupName.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a “VPC Only” customer, and have your Default VPC deleted, then during ingress action , you need to specify the VPC ID (or subnet ID of another VPC). If you do not specify it, then default VPC will be presumed.

In your case, it seems like you have your default VPC deleted. OR You are not passing the VPC ID (or subnet ID of another VPC).

So Either pass the VPC ID (or subnet ID of another VPC) OR have AWS technical support create a new default VPC for you.